# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError when following tutorial

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to use Play! but I always get an error when trying to run a project: `[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

When I do `java -version` or `javac -version`, it confirms I'm using Java 8 by outputting `1.8.0_45`. I don't understand why this error happens, the docs says I NEED java 8 for the latest Play! version, the project has a dependency to Play! 2.4.2.

I followed the documentation: installed activator, added it to the path, generated a new project form the template 'java-play-intro' but when i type `activator` in my project directory, I always get the error above. I tried to use the `update-alternative` command to use java 6 and then 7 but the error is exactly the same.

BUT when I use `activator ui` it works fine !

How is this possible? Am I always supposed to use the UI?

Comment: I had a similar problem, I think there are some issues with java 8 as of now.

Comment: Do you get that error when running from your IDE? Do you have multiple java versions installed (could be Java 8 JDK and a leftover Java 7 JRE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the script you are starting, uses the JAVA_HOME environment variable and not the JDK binaries that can be found on your PATH.